# FTP exclusion in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the below error while trying to active the wordpress theme(University | Education Responsive WordPress Theme) after installing. The theme is paid one.

```
I have skipped the FTP permissions also using the below line

  define('FS_METHOD','direct');

I have also given full permissions(777) to the entire folder.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this.


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function submit_button() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-admin/includes/file.php:2204 
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-content/themes/uoc/include/theme-options/theme_options_functions.php(262): request_filesystem_credentials('themes.php?page...', 'ftpext', false, false, Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-content/themes/uoc/include/theme-options/theme_options_arrays.php(5): cs_get_demo_content('home.json')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-content/themes/uoc/functions.php(517): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-settings.php(497): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/index.php(17): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#8 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ols/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 2204
```

Comment: Maybe your theme is not supporting WP version?

Comment: Supported versions are 5.3.x and below. I'm using 5.3  @Justinas

Comment: There was some problem with the theme I believe because it got installed on windows without any kind of hurdles straightaway. But in ubuntu it is the same and I'm not able to install it @Justinas